# In R shiny, how do I add functionality to the action button "Add"?

Tags: r, shiny, rscript

I am working on the R shiny app. I have created Tab1 and Tab2 in Shiny, and what I am attempting to do is make the datatable visible in "Tab2" once I fill in the below forms and hit the "Add" button.

**Summary**

When the user enters information on "SchoolId, UserId, class, result" in Tab1 and clicks the "Add" button, the Datatable in "Tab2" should appear.

Also, once the user presses the "Add" button, the fields "SchoolId," "UserId," and so on should be empty, ready for the user to fill in the data of the second row in "Tab2."

**Issue:**

I am sure that I am missing something here to build a server-level connection for the "Add" button, because I can't fill in the details for the second row in Tab2 because since "Add" button is not working.

Could someone help to fix this issue?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(stringr)
library(Hmisc)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(V8)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(tabsetPanel(id='tabs'
                           , tabPanel("Tab1", uiOutput("tabP1"))
                           , tabPanel("Tab2", uiOutput("tabP2"))
    )
   
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 output$tabP1 <- renderUI({
    tabPanel("Tap1"
             , div(id = "form"
                   , textInput("schoolId *", label="SchoolId" )
                   , selectInput("userId", label="UserId"
                                 , choices = list("UserA" = "UserA", "UserB" = "UserB",
                                                  
                                                  "UserC" = "UserC")
                                                  
                                                  , selected = "UserA")
                   
                   
                   , textInput("class", value = NA, label = "class")
                   
                   , selectInput("result", label="result"
                                 , choices = list("PASS" = "PASS", "FAIL" ="FAIL" ), selected = "")
                  
             )
             
             , actionButton("add", "Add")
    )
  })
  
 
  # -------------------- Tab2  ----------------------------------
  
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    req(input$schoolId,input$userId,input$class,input$result)
    tmp<-data.frame(SCHOOLID=input$schoolId, USERID=input$userId
                    , CLASS= input$class
                    , RESULT=input$result
                    
    )
    
    df <- rbind(df,tmp)
  })
  output$DT2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df
  })
  
  output$tabP2 <- renderUI({
    tabPanel("View"
             , DT::dataTableOutput("DT2")
             , hr()
             , hidden(downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
             
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use something like `reactive` or `reactiveValues` for values that can be changed over and over. To hide the table until a button is clicked, use a `conditionalPanel` based on the output of the button (it reveals how many times it has been clicked).

I have implemented these things in your code below:

EDIT: Replying to your first comment as well

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(tabsetPanel(id='tabs', 
                       tabPanel("Tab1",
                                div(id = "form", 
                                    textInput("schoolId", label="SchoolId *" ),
                                    selectInput("userId", label="UserId", choices = c("UserA", "UserB", "UserC"),selected = "UserA"), 
                                    textInput("class", label = "class"), 
                                    selectInput("result", label="result", choices = c("PASS", "FAIL" ))
                                    ),
                                actionButton("add", "Add")
                                ), 
                       tabPanel("Tab2", 
                                tabPanel("View", 
                                         conditionalPanel("input.add != 0", 
                                                          DTOutput("DT2"), hr(), downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
                                         )
                                )
                       )
           )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  store <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    new_entry <- data.frame(SCHOOLID=input$schoolId, USERID=input$userId
                            , CLASS= input$class
                            , RESULT=input$result)
    
    if("value" %in% names(store)){
      store$value<-bind_rows(store$value, new_entry)
    } else {
      store$value<-new_entry
    }
    # If you want to reset the field values after each entry use the following two lines
    for(textInputId in c("schoolId", "class")) updateTextInput(session, textInputId, value = "")
    updateSelectInput(session, "userId", selected = "UserA")
    updateSelectInput(session, "result", selected = "PASS")
  })
  output$DT2 <- renderDT({
    store$value
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution,  at present, "Tab2" only shows one row.  I am unable to add additional rows. I also anticipate the rows to be added one by one (in single Datatable) whenever I click the "Add" button.  Additionally, the "Add" button should allow me to empty the typed fields so that the values for subsequent rows can be filled again for the 2nd and 3rd rows, etc. I am looking for your help on this.

Comment: I edited my post to make account for the issues in your comment. If you want to add additional rows, then you append a table instead of overwriting it. To clear fields use the update functions in Shiny to clear them

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine now. Thank you for your assistance with this.